# Global encoding mb_strtoupper

Tags: php, character-encoding

Is it possible to set a global encoding parameter for mb_strtoupper?
Instead of declaring on each call to the function?

```
mb_strtoupper($str, "ISO-8859-1")
```

Comment: what you have tried till now? If you will provide some code work only we at stackoverflow help you

Comment: FlorianR just gave me the answer i needed

Answer (score 3):

you can just change the internal encoding (for all!) 
look documentation: http://php.net/manual/de/function.mb-internal-encoding.php

Answer (score 0):

Try using this

```
  mb_internal_encoding("iso-8859-1");
    mb_http_output( "UTF-8" );
    ob_start("mb_output_handler");
```

mb_internal_encoding is not necessary in PHP 5.6